# Trying to setup an SSH connection from an external Internet connection to a VirtualBox guest OS instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, port-forwarding

I was having problems creating a SSH tunnel—while I was away from home—back to my VirtualBox guest machine back at my house. I did some research using search engines and looking at numerous sites, but still did not accomplish my task.

The [answers in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-VirtualBox-guest-externally-through-a-host) was the closest that I got to almost completing this task. I attempted my own “fix,” but was wondering if there was a better way to SSH back to a guest virtual machine from the Internet?

Here is a quick diagram of my setup:

- `Remote device -> INTERNET -> MODEM -> ROUTER -> HOST MACHINE -> GUEST VM`
- `Remote device (SSH client) -> PASS THRU DEVICES -> GUEST VM (ssh server)`
- `Remote device (leave SSH port 3022) -> INTERNET -> MODEM -> ROUTER (FWD from port 3022 to 3022) --> HOST MACHINE (FWD from port 3022 to to port 22) -> GUEST VM (arrive ssh port 22)`

Answer (score 0):

The [answers provided by other users here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-VirtualBox-guest-externally-through-a-host) helped me to accomplish the task of connecting from out on the internet to my home computer's guest machine.  You should be able to connect using computers, tablets, and smart phones (android, IPhone,etc).  I add a few more step in case it might be helpful to someone else:

Here is a quick diagram of my setup:

- `Remote device -> INTERNET -> MODEM -> ROUTER -> HOST MACHINE -> GUEST VM`
- `Remote device (SSH client) -> PASS THRU DEVICES -> GUEST VM (SSH server)`
- `Remote device (leave SSH port 3022) -> INTERNET -> MODEM -> ROUTER (from port 3022 to 3022)--> HOST MACHINE (from port 3022 to 22 -> GUEST VM (arrive ssh port 22)`

The key for me was to realize that ALL connections  was `PASSING-THROUGH`  intermediary devices to get from my remote PC  to  my guest virtual-machine at home… Hence port forwarding!

Notes:

- Need SSH client to request a secure connection and a running ssh server to process the secure connection.
- I will forward the port 3022 as used in the chosen answer from above.
- Enter your IPs where needed (home modem/router, host IP, guest IP,etc.), Names chosen are just examples-use or change.

1. Create ssh tunnel to port 3022 on your modem's IP / router's external IP address.

```
 ssh client/device possible commands: ssh -p 3022 user-name@home_external_IP
```

2. Port forward = we are passing thru the connection from router to host machine

   - Also make sure firewall /IPtable rules on router is allowing ports to be forward (open if needed)
   - Router's Pfwd SCREEN required entries: AppName:SSH_Fwd, Port_from: 3022,  Protocol:both (UDP/TCP), IP_address:hostIP_address,  Port_to:3022, everything else can be blank
   - DD-wrt router software resources / Info:
   - http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding
   - http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP
3. Host Machine Firewall: open port 3022  #so forwarded port can pass thru to guest machine

   - Host Machine: Install VirtualBox, guest additions, and guest machine if not done already
   - Configure guest machine and then follow the Network section below
   - I used VirtualBox GUI to setup guest's network- easier than CLI
   - If you want to use other methods:  VirtualBox /manual/ch06.html#natforward
4. Some suggest using Network Bridge adapter for guest= access to LAN and other machines on your LAN.  This also pose an increase security risk, because now your guest machine is now exposed to LAN machines and possibly  the INTERNET hackers if firewall not setup properly.  So I selected Network adapter attached to NAT for less exposure to bridged security risks.

On the guest machine do the following:

- Guest Machine VirtualBox Network settings: Adapter 1:Attached to NAT,
- Guest Machine VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rule: Name:External_SSH, Protocol:TCP, Host Port: 3022,  Guest Port 22, Host&guest IPs:leave blank
- Click on advance in Network section then click on Port forwarding to enter rules
- Guest Machine Firewall: open port 22  #so SSH connection can enter
- Guest Machine: Make sure that ssh server is installed, configured properly, and running
- LINUX test to see if ssh server running: sudo service ssh status
- Can check netstat to see if connection made to port 22 on the guest machine

Also there are different SSH servers and clients depending on platform using.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients

For Ubuntu Users:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

That should be it.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @JakeGould - Your edits look really good.  I will review changes and learn how to format my future posts.  Thanks again for your help.